# MySQL subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query which goes like this:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select meta_value 
        from nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'firm' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
        as firm, 
    (select meta_value f
        rom nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'first_name' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
    as first_name, 
    (select meta_value 
        from nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'last_name' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
    as last_name     
    from nord_submissions s 
    order by created_at desc
```

Now I need to narrow it down with a where clause like this:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select meta_value 
        from nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'firm' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
        as firm, 
    (select meta_value 
        from nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'first_name' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
    as first_name, 
    (select meta_value 
        from nord_usermeta m 
        where meta_key = 'last_name' and user_id = s.user_id 
        limit 1) 
    as last_name 

    from nord_submissions s 
    where firm like '%DG%' 
    order by created_at desc
```

The problem obviously is in way i use subquery but i cant find a way to reference it in where clause.
Please help.

Comment: "The problem" .. what problem?  Can you please expand your question with error messages / sample database schema / sample data etc - maybe even a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html

Comment: **firm** is a user defined column..we can call it imaginary column too..and WHERE only works with database column. you should try with `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why go so Long...try with SELF JOIN ( joining same tables in query )..see below *(not tested)*

```
 SELECT ns.*,
        um1.meta_value AS firmName,
        um2.meta_value AS firstName,
        um3.meta_value AS lastName
 FROM nord_submission ns
 INNER JOIN nord_usermeta um1 USING(id) AND meta_key = 'firm'
 INNER JOIN nord_usermeta um2 USING(id) AND meta_key = 'first_name'
 INNER JOIN nord_usermeta um3 USING(id) AND meta_key = 'last_name'
 WHERE um1.meta_value LIKE '%DG%'
 ORDER BY ns.created_at
```

**Note:** if both table have different column name , by which u refrence each other, then you can replace  `USING(id)` with `ns.user_id`=`um1.user_id` and so on

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use keys rather than columns you'll have to let the application sort it out. Using so many sub-queries you'll see a performance hit.

```
SELECT *
FROM nord_submissions 
 INNER JOIN nord_usermeta 
 USING (user_id)
WHERE (meta_key='last_name' or meta_key='first_name' or (meta_key='firm' and meta_value LIKE '%DG%') )
ORDER BY created_at desc
```

Comment: It's not exactly wrong (when you delete the `AND firm like..` !), but it's not as nicely formatted (yours will have multiple rows, whereas OP's and diEcho's query will have only one row per nord_submissions row. Anyway, I'll edit the above mentioned `AND firm..` out and +1 for your effort and alternative solution.